# It is taking too much time to logout from my webapplication

Tags: vb.net

In my vb.net web application when the user tries to logout then it takes around 10-20 seconds to logout. In between this process at bottom-left of the browser it displays uploading and after uploading 100% user is able to logout from the application.

I want fast logout from my web application. I am unable to solve this problem .

My application had already deployed on webserver. I only have the problem on my webserver. On my local machine it is OK.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using WebForms? How big is your viewstate? That all needs to be posted back to the server before it can respond.

Comment: yes i m using WebForms
did u mean that all the viewstates must be post back to the server when i try to logout?

Comment: Yes. Every time you do a "postback" in WebForms, you are sending back the entire form to the .NET web server. You should use the Network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools (press F12 when running your site in Chrome) to see how big this request is. You may need to tick "Preserve log" to see it.

Comment: The Network tab will also show you how long each step takes, which will tell you where the problem is. Just hover your mouse over the rectange on the right for the post request after you click logout. If it spends most of that 10-20 seconds sending the data, you know it is because the amount of data to send is too big. If it is spending most of that time waiting around, then your server is responding too slowly. Can we access your webserver ourselves to test it?

Comment: Also, where are you located and where is the web server located? It might have been fast on your machine because you can send a large amount of data to yourself very quickly. But when you have to send it to another machine across the world, it has to go through the internet, which is much, much slower.

Comment: ya i saw that it's take time to logout 
but now question is that how to resolve this ??

Comment: Did you read my comments carefully? I asked a lot of clarifying questions you have not answered. Until you answer those questions, we cannot help you any further, sorry.

Comment: ya you are right sir but it is not possible because i m an employee so i don't have rights for that..

Comment: Okay, so we can't get access to your webserver ourselves. Which means you need to do what I suggested and see _which part_ of the logout request is taking all the time: sending the data to the server, waiting for the server to respond, or receiving the response from the server. Without that information, I cannot tell where the problem lies,

Comment: CONNECTION SETUP       TIME    STALLED  1.000MS
REQUEST SENT  2.0 MIN                             
WAITING   6.70S                  
CONTENT DOWNLOAD         12.930

TOTAL TIME 2.12 SEC

Comment: at bottom-left of the browser it displays uploading and after uploading 100% completed  user going to get default login page

Comment: application hosted on the server which is at client side and i can access this server by vpn client

Comment: as i m new at stack overflow, i can not able to send screen shots of that

Comment: So it looks like it took 2 minutes to send the data. That is pretty ridiculous. What did it say in the Size column of the network inspector? You can also click on the row and then go to the Headers tab. Have a look at how much Form Data it is sending.

Comment: ya sir this is pretty ridiculous .
In size content what you  mentioned ,when i generate report its content download size is 8 mb 
and when i click on logout same page conten download size is 360-bytes  and redirect to login page it's size is 3-4 kb

Comment: If you right-click in the Network tab, you should be able to "Copy all as HAR". Can you do that and paste the text into something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JustPasteIt](http://justpaste.it) or similar and post the link so I can have a look? That way I can see info on all the requests myself.

Comment: sorry sir, i got some fever so i was unable to answer u
sorry for inconvenience
now sir as u say i try to upload the file u say but it is not working the file size of .har is 6 mb

Comment: Put it in dropbox or some other free file uploading service, then. Maybe zip it up first. Share the link here and I will look at it for you.

Comment: find here the link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/403cmwwmubxspor/server.rar?dl=0

Comment: Okay, so when you post back to the server, you are sending 2.75MB of data _just to logout_. This is one of the major downsides of using WebForms. You need to look into reducing the size of your viewstate in .NET 2.0 (which it looks like you are using). I don't remember the specifics, but there are ways to disable the viewstate for a particular control which doesn't need it. Research what viewstate is, and when it is safe to disable it, and do that for as much as you can on that page, especially for the big table if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the HAR file you posted, I can see that when you post back to the server, you are sending 2.75MB of data just to logout. This is one of the major downsides of using WebForms. You need to look into reducing the size of your viewstate in .NET 2.0 (which it looks like you are using).

You can disable the viewstate for a particular control that doesn't need it using `EnableViewState="false"`.

Research what viewstate is, and when it is safe to disable it, and do that for as much as you can on that page, especially for the big table if possible.

#### Alternative: Logout using a WebMethod

If you cannot reduce the ViewState size correctly without breaking things, you may want to look into having a WebMethod that you can call from the browser using jQuery. Dave Ward has a number of excellent posts on how to do this on his website Encosia, such as [this one](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/). The advantage is that the call to the webmethod should be very small, which will be much quicker than trying to send 2.7MB just to logout.

The potential downsides are that you may need to do extra work in Javascript for a logout to work correctly. For example, you may need to clear the session cookie manually afterwards, and do the redirect yourself back to the `default.aspx` page.

---

It is situations like these that highlight just how far the web has progressed. WebForms in ASP.NET 2.0 were an important step in making the web easier to program on for Windows desktop programmers, but it is not the way the web should work nowadays, and is a slow, kludgy, outdated technology. If you can convince people to stop using it and start using ASP.NET MVC instead, you won't run into these kinds of scenarios again.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your valuable time and more importantly your answers are too clear to understand the things.

Comment: If this answer has helped you, you should accept it (click the tick mark next to my answer) and, optionally, upvote it. Good luck with your further pursuits. If you get stuck again, you should raise a new question with as much detail as you can give for us to have the full details with which to understand the problem.